# How to place image on same line with Text in menu

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to place my small image on exactly the same place than the text

So i'm able to achieve it but the image is a little bit up, and need to b moved a bit left.

Can you please assist?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 6px solid #4CAF50;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Vertical Menu</h1>

<div class="vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://www.tsishipping.com/storage/app/media/_mediathumbs/interstate%20shipping%20new%20mexico-img-3-386af11858050a81cdd53b7b6eeabdb6.png" alt="Girl in a jacket" height="16" width="18">Link 100</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your image is left aligned with the text, it just has a transparent margin in the image itself. You may want to crop the image.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: The vertical alignment can probably be fixed by applying `vertical-align:text-bottom` to the image. Frankly, though, I'd be using a pseudo-element with a background image rather than an *actual* image here.

Comment: Use an image editor, and remove the extra empty space around your image. There are plenty of free editors around, and tutorials if you need help.

Comment: @DBS   I can't cause the images I'm placing it are links to their image Database given to us by provider companies.  Is it possible to use transparent/opacity or something else ?

Comment: You can manually bump the image left with various different CSS properties (e.g. `margin-left: -4px` ), though this is a rather nasty solution and the alignment will be inconsistent if the images ever change.

Comment: @DBS  thanks. I also used your code and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
img {
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}
```

I've updated your code. Try this.

```css
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 6px solid #4CAF50;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

img {
 position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Vertical Menu</h1>

<div class="vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://www.tsishipping.com/storage/app/media/_mediathumbs/interstate%20shipping%20new%20mexico-img-3-386af11858050a81cdd53b7b6eeabdb6.png" alt="Girl in a jacket" height="16" width="18">Link 100</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
</div>
```